# Space requiremnt for German embassy visa

Tags: citizenship

I would like to know if my visa will be approved by Germany embassy if I apply to live with my husband his 2 parents and his little brother. The house is 100m square.2 toilets 3 rooms 1 kitchen and bathroom 1 sitting room

Comment: What is your husband's residence status in Germany?

Comment: What are both your nationalities?

Comment: My husband is a German citizen and I am Kenyan citizen

Answer (score 3):

Well that was a struggle!  I eventually found:

> “Without prejudice to state provisions, sufficient living
>   space is usually deemed to be available if 12 sqm of
>   living space are available to each family member aged
>   above six and 10 sqm of living space for each family
>   member aged below six. Adequate availability of the
>   facilities (kitchen, bathrooms, lavatories) must be ensured.
>   A shortfall of about ten per cent is acceptable”
>   (2.4.2. General Administrative Regulation to the Residence
>   Act).

That is a quote from [this PDF](http://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/EN/Publikationen/EMN/Studien/wp73-emn-familiennachzug-drittstaatsangehoerige-deutschland.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) on the BAMF (Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge) website.

There will be a total of five of you, so with a 100 sqm house you will have 20 sqm each.  The only *possible* catch is what "100 sqm" means.  The space within an apartment counts fully, but cellars don't, and outside balconies count 25% etc.  See [this answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/14950/14680) for more details. 
 However it is unlikely that will bring you under the 12 sqm figure; also, if you got the 100sqm from the property details (rather than your husband getting out a tape measure), they will already have done any necessary pro-rating.

Comment: The point of my comment on the question, in case it was not obvious, is that these requirements should not be relevant if the application is made under the EU free movement directive.

Comment: @phoog - no, it was not obvious.  Good point though.

Comment: I wonder if there's any Londoners earning less than median wage that meet those generous German space requirements.